# Menu <li>'s divided into columns&rows not behaving when sub-menu <ul> is opened

Tags: jquery, css

I have an issue that's been driving me bananas for the entire day...

What I have is a bunch of `<li>` menu items, one of which opens an `<ul>` sub menu. The problem is, I can't get the surrounding `<li>`'s to behave and take the sub menu into account when repositioning themselves.

Demo (click on 'MISC'): http://jsfiddle.net/6a3eZ/

How it SHOULD behave is this (I can only get it to work properly when the drop-down menu item is in the third column): http://jsfiddle.net/6a3eZ/3/

Here's my CSS:

```
#menu {
    position:fixed;
    width:303px;
    margin: 62px 10px 0 0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:9999;
    right:0;
    background:#EFEFEF;
    display:visible;

    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
    box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}
.menu-active {
    display:block !important;
}

.menu {
    text-align:center;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.menu a {
    height:100px;
    color:#999;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 1px 1px 0;
    display:block;
    font-family:'Montserrat',arial,tahoma,verdana;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#fff;
}
.menu a:hover, .menu a:active {
    color:#fff;
    background:#999;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.menu ul {

}
.menu li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:-1;
    width:100px;
}
.menu li:first-child {
    border-top:none !important;
}
.menu li a {
    font-size:10px;
}
ul.sub-menu {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    padding:0;
    width:300px;
}
.second ul.sub-menu {
    margin:0 0 0 -100px;
}
.sub-menu li {
    heigh:100px;
    float:left;
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:red;
    width:100px;
}
.sub-menu a {
    display:block;
    color:#888;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100px;
}
.menu li.sub a {
    background: url(images/menu-expandable.png);
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
/* Retina display .menu li.sub a */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       only screen and (min-resolution: 240dpi)
{
.menu li.sub a { 
    background: url(images/menu-expandable@2x.png);
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 18px 7px;
}
}
.menu li.sub a:hover {
}
.menu li.sub > ul a {
    background-image: none;
    font-size:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/6a3eZ/8/

The animation is a problem still, but im sure that you can correct that since you wrote it, but this will fix your css issue.

```
#menu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EFEFEF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
    display: block;
    margin: 62px 10px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 303px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.menu01 {
    width: 310px;
}

.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Looks good but I can't seem to pin down where the extra padding between the menu blocks is coming from?

Comment: add vertical-align: middle; to your .menu li css. There is still some in the gutters causing you problems though. So increase the width of menu01 to 315px, and remove from .menu a your margin: 0 1px 1px 0.

Comment: Ok, looks like I've done it. It was the "display:inline-block" that was causing the extra margin. A little negative margin took care of that. Huge thanks for your help, and the other poster was dead on too. I'm choosing this one as the answer though as it followed the same styling etc. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it this way:

HTML:

```
<style>
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
ul{list-style:none; width: 408px;}
li{float:left; width:100px; height: 100px; font-family:tahoma; text-align:center; line-height:100px; border:1px solid #ccc; margin:1px;}   
ul ul{display:none;}
#item3{background: #eee;}
.sub{background: #cee;}
</style>

<ul id="nav">
    <li id="1">One <ul><li>sub a</li><li>sub b</li><li>sub c</li></ul></li>
    <li id="2">Two <ul><li>sub d</li><li>sub e</li><li>sub f</li></ul></li>
    <li id="3">Three <ul><li>sub e</li><li>sub f</li><li>sub g</li></ul></li>
    <li id="4">Four <ul><li>sub h</li><li>sub i</li><li>sub j</li></ul></li>
    <li id="5">Five <ul><li>sub k</li><li>sub k</li><li>sub l</li></ul></li>
    <li id="6">Six <ul><li>sub m</li><li>sub n</li><li>sub o</li></ul></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

    $('#nav > li').on('click', function(){   
       // console.log('click');
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        is_new = true;

        if($('.sub').length){ 
            is_new = ($('.sub').first().attr('data-parent') !== id);            
            $('.sub').remove();
        }

        if(is_new){
            var $sub = $(this).children('ul').clone();
            var index = Math.floor($(this).index() / 3) * 3;
            var after = $('#nav > li').eq(index+2);
            $sub.children('li').addClass('sub').attr('data-parent', id).insertAfter(after); 
        }
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/6a3eZ/7/

Answer (score 0):

Add to your .sub-menu class this.

```
element.style {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   visibility: visible;
}
```

This will get you the results you are looking for.

Comment: Again, not what I'm looking for I'm afraid. This solution too opens the sub menu over the lower menu items. I need it to push them down like in the second jsfiddle I linked to.

Comment: I think I have it figured out, give me a sec

Comment: I'm hopeful someone will be able to crack this :)

Comment: Why not do 3 sets of ul's? 1 for the top 1 for the dropdown and 1 for the bottom? Or is this suppose to be responsive?

Comment: The reason your second jsfiddle works is because your margins push Gallery down correctly.

Comment: The menu is generated by WordPress, so I can't create a new ul for each item. Also, what you said about the second jsfiddle is true, however the first is using the exact same method, with margins set to make it appear in the correct place. But it's not pushing down the lower items. For some reason, while the red sub-menu is set to be the full width of the menu, it's only pushing the lower items off by one. For example, if the 'misc' menu would be in the first column, then when opened, there would be 2 lower menu items overlapping the red sub-menu.